# Where is the Center of a HTC Vive Controller?

Tags: virtual-reality, htc-vive

OpenVR (aka SteamVR) provides the position of the vive controller. The question is where that point is exactly located on the controller itself?

[image]

To be more specific, where (on the hardware) the following method call (from [OpenVR](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/9d48ccf90d709382a137de9bc429aab5f7cea5de/headers/openvr.h)) refers to?

```
virtual void GetDeviceToAbsoluteTrackingPose( ETrackingUniverseOrigin eOrigin, float fPredictedSecondsToPhotonsFromNow, VR_ARRAY_COUNT(unTrackedDevicePoseArrayCount) TrackedDevicePose_t *pTrackedDevicePoseArray, uint32_t unTrackedDevicePoseArrayCount ) = 0;
```

Comment: I think its the Red dot I can not Confirm it but i am pretty sure when ever is cast a ray or draw some GL line from controllers center it always came from the red dot u draw

Answer (score 3):

Open the 3D model (located in Steam\steamapps\common\SteamVR\resources\rendermodels\vr_controller_vive_1_5\vr_controller_vive_1_5.obj) in a modelling tool such as Blender. It will place the controller right on its origin so you can measure it exactly. It's closest to the red dot as you can see here:

[image]